# c code has small limit

Tags: c, windows-7

I am test and tuning a protocol. When I run the following code, it crashes when I make my array size larger say..300000. It runs at 200000. The number seems awfully small. Is it my PC, my code? Please help. My goal is to see how fast I can do simple math, write to a file,close the file, read from the file after opening and write to another file. I am using Codeblocks GNU GCC compiler on win7. I also get different numbers from what I expect at the bottom of dig2.txt.( not increasing by 2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
printf("Hello Test\n");
FILE *fp;
FILE *fp2;
FILE *fp3;
int a;
int sizofFile = 300000;
int pix[sizofFile];
int pix2[sizofFile];
fp = fopen("dig.txt", "w+");
for (a = 0; a<(sizofFile); a = a + 1){
    pix[a]=a * 2; //load the array
    }
    fwrite(pix, sizeof(a), sizofFile, fp);  //stream data to file
printf("Good bye Test \n");
fclose(fp); //close first file
fp2 = fopen("dig.txt", "r"); // reopen file to read
fp3 = fopen("dig2.txt", "w+"); // open a write file for human vision
fread(pix2, sizeof(a), sizofFile, fp2);
for (a = 0; a < sizofFile; a = a + 1){
    fprintf(fp3, "%d \n", pix2[a]); // make human readable
    }
fclose(fp2);
fclose(fp3);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: try long instead of int

Comment: try `malloc` instead of auto variable.

Comment: Please employ a normal code formatting style - this is unreadable

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744650/how-to-overcome-stack-size-issue-with-visual-studio-running-c-codes-with-big-ar

Comment: The code appeared more readable initially but the forum machine forced me to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Local/auto arrays storage size depends on the stack size / auto variable storage. You could increase it using compiler options, but that's not the best way.

You should use data allocated with `malloc` instead, the limit is much, much higher (only depends on the process memory limit / physical memory of the computer). That's how big arrays should be allocated.

```
int *pix = malloc(sizofFile * sizeof(int));
int *pix2 = malloc(sizofFile * sizeof(int));
```

use like you're doing now, then before leaving `free` the memory

```
free(pix); free(pix2);
```