# Process finished with exit code -107341571 (0xC00000FD)

Tags: python, windows, runtime-error, exit-code

I am getting

> Process finished with exit code -107341571 (0xC00000FD)

With no stack trace, or any other indication of an error, in a rather large code-base.

I can't create a reproducible, or I would be able to solve this.

What's causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, this happened with the following code in some class:

```
class A():
    @property
    def points_limits(self):
        return self.points_limits
```

Calling `a.points_limits` crashed Python.
This is an obvious name-clash, and I expected some compilation error in such cases, but apparently this is not caught.

---

##### Solution:

don't call a property within itself - return a member variable instead, notice the leading underscore:

```
    @property
    def points_limits(self):
        return self._points_limits
```

---

Why there is nothing more indicative, or why Google doesn't find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311584/913098) is beyond me.

Comment: Weird. I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khp5x.png) that is a bit more indicative. At least showing the exact line `return self.points_limits` and complaining about a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. How are you running? conda? IPython? Regular?

Comment: I am running a system interpreter with no env [there are bad reasons out of my control to doing this].