# Trying to run Flask app on PyCharm, getting exit code -1073741571. What's the issue?

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I am running a flask application on my computer in PyCharm and suddenly it stopped working. Nothing changed since last time when it worked fine. Does anyone know what this error code means?

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 231.9011.38)

* Serving Flask app 'app.py'
* Debug mode: off
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
  Press CTRL+C to quit

Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

There are no errors in the PyCharm log files and I didn't manage to find anything about what this error is all about but definitely looks like some internal timeout error because the app is running for a while trying to load the page before popping this.

I even created a new virtual environment and get rid of the unused packages but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a great coincidence, that is a stack overflow error... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629027/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741571